# How to type data in the context of useFetch in nuxt3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a type like so:

```
export type Tenant = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

And in a nuxt vue template like so (Should be in composable when working):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { Tenant } from '~/types/models'

  const { data:tenants, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch<Tenant []>('http://localhost:3000/tenants', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': auth.headers.Authorization
    },
    transform: (_tenants) => _tenants.tenants,
  })
</script>
```

My issue is that I would like to cast the result to "Tenant". The result json from the API is a collection ested in "tenants", that is why I added the transform part.

My typescript validation though complains like this:

```
Property 'tenants' does not exist on type 'Tenant[]'.
```

Which is in line

```
    transform: (_tenants) => _tenants.tenants,
```

I am not sure about what is the recommended way to convert a json structure to an object for better maintenance.

Thanks loads for insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a solution for that by not casting the result through useFetch but instead within the transform section like adding an interface to it.

```
    transform: (_data) => (_data as TransformedData).tenant as Tenant,

    ...

    interface TransformedData {
        tenant: Tenant
    }
```

After finding this solution, I moved further and actually did not use transform but used onResponse instead:

```
          onResponse({ response }) {
            const tenant = response._data.tenant as Tenant;
            // store tenant data in store 
          },
```